# newbie formula question - returning text if one value greater than another and both greater than 0

Tags: formula

Trying to create a formula field that returns text "Thank you for increasing your giving."

```
IF npo02__OppAmountThisYearHH__c   >   npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c
    AND  npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c > 0
```

I cannot figure out how to create this logic.

Answer (score 3):

```
IF(
    AND(
        npo02__OppAmountThisYearHH__c > npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c,npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c > 0
    ),
    'Thank you for increasing your giving.','FALSE TEXT'
)
```

I used the *AND()* formula within the *IF()* statement which can be replaced by the **&&** operator like so:

```
IF(
    npo02__OppAmountThisYearHH__c > npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c && npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c > 0,
    'Thank you for increasing your giving.','FALSE TEXT'
)
```